# R - How Do I Force Installation of My Custom Package to Fail When Imported Package Version is Too Old?

Tags: r, analytics

I've been working on a custom R library at work. I use functions from a couple different packages (always qualified with ::), so I've added them to the Imports section of my DESCRIPTION file. When I use `R CMD INSTALL` to install my package, I get a warning if the version of an imported package is too old, but installation continues. How do I force it to fail and alert the user that they need to update that package? I don't want to add any of them to the Depends section because I don't want those extra packages loaded when my library is loaded.

Example DESCRIPTION file:

`Depends:
  R (>= 3.1.2)
Imports: 
  dplyr (>= 0.7.0)`

If dplyr 0.5.0 is loaded on the user's system, installation continues, but certain functions that depend on dplyr 0.7.0 will fail when called.

Comment: do you need the failure upon installation? wouldn't it be fine to have it `.onLoad()` instead?

Comment: I think failure on installation makes more sense. I wouldn't want somebody using the library to believe they've successfully installed my library and all of its dependencies only to find out that's false when they actually try to use it. I think it's also more consistent with how other packages act. For example, dplyr installation fails if the system has an out-of-date version of one of its imports.

That's just my thinking though, if you've got a good argument for `.onLoad()`, I'd be glad to hear it. Obviously I'm not an expert on this stuff since I can't figure this out haha.

Comment: @RolandASc I think I misunderstood what you were suggesting. I see now that when I run `R CMD INSTALL`, there's a section toward the end that says "`** testing if installed package can be loaded`." I think that's actually where dplyr notifies the user that an imported package is too old.
  
Do you have a suggestion on how to properly do what I'm attempting to do? I see from a couple sources that an `.onLoad()` function is usually defined in a file called `zzz.R`. What I'm wondering is what's the best way to get the list of packages under Imports in my DESCRIPTION file to check versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using `find.package`, `packageDescription` and `packageVersion`:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  myImports <- strsplit(utils::packageDescription(pkgname)[["Imports"]], split = ",\\s")[[1]]
  if (length(find.package("dplyr", quiet = TRUE)) > 0) {
    reqVers <- grep("^dplyr [(]", myImports, value = TRUE)
    reqVers <- sub("^dplyr [(]>= ([0-9]+.*[0-9]+).*", "\\1", reqVers)
    if (check <- utils::packageVersion("dplyr") < reqVers)
      stop("Dplyr is version ", utils::packageVersion("dplyr"), " --- this package requires version ", reqVers, " at least")
  }
  invisible()
}
```

Like you say in the comment, common practice is to put this into a file called `zzz.R`.

Of course you could also replace the `stop` with a `warning`.

Comment: Thank you. Used a slightly modified version of this to check versions of all packages listed in my DESCRIPTION file.